# How to remove first 80 characters form a char array?

Tags: arrays, c, char, c-strings

I've my char array, that has maximum size 1024. Anyway it contains a string of 200 characters. I want to remove exactly the first 80 characters from this 200 characters string. How can I do it?

```
    char my_array[1024];
     for(int i = 80; i < sizeof(my_array); i+=1)
 {
    my_array[i-80] = my_array[i];
 }
```

I tryed this, but it doesn't work. Do you know any solution to do this? Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: How does it not work? What happens? What did you expect to happen? How do you check? **Do you have any warnings from your compiler?**

Comment: and the `sizeof`works with `max_array`

Comment: sorry, it was an oversight. obviously also inside the braces the array is my_array

Comment: Do you really remove it? Or do you just want a string that starts 80 `char`s later? If it is the later one, you can just create a pointer pointing to the middle of the array.

Comment: What do you mean by character?

Comment: I just want to remove the first 80 characters.

Comment: How do you check if you removed the characters?

Comment: for me a character is a single letter (for example "A")

Comment: printf("%s\n", my_array)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.  But I don't see your initial 200-character string, and I don't see your attempt to print out the modified string.  I suspect your problem has to do with something we can't see, that you haven't posted.

Comment: Try `my_array[80] = '!';` before the backwards move.

Comment: Your wrong variable names in the question are one reason why you should post exact complete code you compile and that reproduces the problem. Just copy&paste your code instead of retyping something loosely inspired by your code. Together with input, output and expected output. There is still no hint in your question why you think the code does not work.

Comment: If you just copy elements, you are leaving the last 80 characters in place.  Are you wanting to return a 1024 element array or a 944 element array?

Comment: The only thing wrong with the code your posted -- and it's not your problem -- is that you're copying more characters than you need to.  You only need to copy 200 - 80 + 1 = 121 characters.  But you're copying 1024 - 80 = 944 characters, including 823 bytes past the end of your 200-character string that don't matter.  But, again, this isn't your problem.  I tested the code you posted, and it works perfectly.  So your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @WonderWhy How do you define letter? Are `,.;" \n`... letters? Is `\r\n` 1 or 2 letters? Is "" (which has multiple code points) a single character? Is 역 1 or 3 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard C string function `memmove`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

memmove( my_array, my_array + 80, strlen( my_array ) - 79 );
```

The magic number `79` means that you need to copy all characters in the string except `80` characters but including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

You need to guarantee that the array indeed contains a string and that the stored string has length (`strlen( my_array )`) not less than `80` characters.

For example

```
size_t n = strlen( my_array );
if ( !( 80 < n ) )
{
    myarray[0] = '\0';
}
else
{
    memmove( my_array, my_array + 80, n - 79 );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that removes first 7 characters from a string stored in a character array.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello World";
    size_t n = 6;
    
    puts( s );
    
    memmove( s, s + n, strlen( s ) - n + 1 );
    
    puts( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
World
```

Comment: This does not necessary remove 80 characters. It removes 80 `char`s, but a character may need more than a single `char`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 sizeof( char ) is always equal to 1.

Comment: Yes, but that has nothing to do with my comment. My point is that a character may need more than 1 `char`. A single character can be a combination of multiple Unicode code points, and a Unicode code point can be longer than 1 `char`. He didn't ask for a way to remove 80 `char`s, he asked for 80 characters (which is actually not that easy to define).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 There is nothing said about other coding system in the question.

Comment: Most systems that use some meaningful form of encoding (means, not a simple microcontroller that only uses bytes, integers, ...) use a encoding that isn't 1 `char` == 1 character. Therefore, the difference between `char` and character is meaningful and should be noted. Don't say character when you mean `char`. When you change your string to `"üa0123456789"`, only `"ü"` will be removed (assuming UTF8) and not 6 nor 7 characters as your text incorrectly says. `s/character/char/` and your answer would be correct.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I am sorry but I do not understand why you have wrote all this to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the array, you could, depending on your need, just create a pointer pointing to the 81th `char` of the original string, this pointer now points to a string where 80 `char` are removed. Here a shorter example with just 10 `char`s removed.

```
int main(void)
{
  char orig[]="This is a long string";
  char *s=orig+10;
  puts(s);
  return 0;
}
```

This will print

```
long string
```

### Character counting problem:

You said you want to remove characters. A `char` is not the same as a character, which is not simple to define and hard to count. First, you have to know the encoding and the value of `CHAR_BIT`. Most likely you will use UTF-8 and `CHAR_BIT==8`. Counting code points is relatively easy, just count the `char`s which indicate the beginning of a code point (Bit 7 is 0 or Bit 6 is set). But then it gets complicated. You need to be aware of [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) which are code points that are combined with other code points to create a single character. Which is also harder because, depending on the context, a character can't be combined. Then you need to define how you count. For example, in Korean, multiple simple "characters" can be combined into a single "character" by placing them in a single square, how do you count them? (Disclamer i don't understand Korean and i don't really understand how Korean works.)

Counting character goes beyond this answer, i only want to show you that "removing 80 characters" isn't easy to define.